# Iterating through a string two characters at a time

Tags: python, string, iteration

I have a string of data that I need to read the first two characters from, use, and then discard.

For example,

```
code = '2436444423'
```

I want to take the '24' assign it to a value 'x' and delete the '24' from the original string leaving it as:

```
code = '36444423'
```

and then assign '36' to 'y', delete it, '44' to 'z' and so on until the original string is empty.

Comment: `v, w, x, y, z = [code[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(code), 2)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (in python 3 its `zip_longest` ) to get the expected pairs :

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> args = [iter(code)] * 2
>>> [''.join(k) for k in izip_longest(*args)]
['24', '36', '44', '44', '23']
```

Then you can simply assign your values to variables and use `int` if you want the integer type of numbers :

```
>>> x,y,z,j,p=[int(''.join(k)) for k in izip_longest(*args)]
>>> (x,y,z,j,p)
(24, 36, 44, 44, 23)
```

Comment: Kasra : An easy way. If the # chars are even,  re.findall('..','1234567890'). If the # chars are odd  re.findall('..?','123456789')

Comment: An alternative and very easy way: Just use, twoCharList = re.findall('..?', '123456789'). This will work whether the number of chars are either odd or even.

Comment: @mario23 Yes its a good solution but not for long strings!

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
code = '2436444423'
code = iter(code)
for x in code:
    print x, next(code)
```

Comment: I don't think this is very readable; at first blush I would never guess that this has anything to do with pairs. And `explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: There's no assignment. In fact, you'd be better off using zips instead of looping through a string and iterator simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a generator:

```
code = '2436444423'
g = (''.join(t) for t in zip(*[iter(code)]*2))
x, y = next(g), next(g)
z = next(g)
```

This can also be a list comprehension that evaluates to `['24', '36', '44', '44', '23']`.

```
[''.join(t) for t in zip(*[iter(code)]*2)]
```

Disclaimer: this doesn't change the binding of the variable `code` at any point. Also if the length of code is odd, it will not return the last character.

Comment: Shashank: Can you please consider my answer in the comment of the next answer? It works when the # chars are ODD too.

Comment: @mario23 I read your answer and it's good, but I don't think it would make sense in my answer. Maybe you can post an answer of your own that is focused on `re` module?